# Dark scroll bar in dark theme in Chromium-based browsers

Tags: feature-request, design, dark-mode

Could you please make a dark scroll bar in Chromium-based browsers in a dark theme by adding the `color-scheme: dark;` property to the dark theme CSS file?

Comment: Could you please explain the benefits of doing so?

Comment: @DialFrost I'd assume the benefits are the same for as any reason to create a dark mode feature for anything; it's easier on the eyes.  In this case, it would also go along with the feature in question.

Comment: @Daedalus isn't wrong. A white scrollbar (or any white GUI control for that matter other than text) really messes up the GUI of whatever you're using and then your eyes have trouble adjusting because it's like you're flickering between light and dark mode every 2 seconds.

Comment: Here is an example of [a page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73367882/custom-cursor-if-else-issue-cursor-jumpy) where a scrollbar may appear.

Comment: Here is [how it looks in Firefox](https://pmortensen.eu/temp2/DarkScrollbars_Firefox.png) (in dark mode). Firefox 103.0 on Linux (Ubuntu with the terrible [GNOME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME)).

Comment: @DialFrost when using a dark theme in the system (and, accordingly, in Chrome) and on Stack Overflow, the scroll bar remains the only element that is not adapted to the dark theme, which spoils the appearance of the page. Take a look at the screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/ryfzE39.png